# rails server eventmachine segfault

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, eventmachine

Performing >rails server yields:

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0.beta.4.1-x86-mingw32/lib/
```

eventmachine.rb:179: [BUG] Segmentation fault

I have nothing else but google..

Answer (score 0):

there were some problems (relate to the numbers of FD) with the latest ruby version (>= 1.9.3) on windows. try updating eventmachine to 1.0.0 stable, it should solve your problem.

Comment: Using eventmachine (1.0.0.beta.4.1)

Comment: You can also try a pure Ruby EM implementation if C fails:
`gem 'eventmachine', "~> 1.0.0", :require => ['em/pure_ruby', 'eventmachine']`